# How to make Image change to show it is being pressed?

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, mobile-safari

I am working on a project for a mobile bidding system. I am designing the front end of it and ran into a problem with the two buttons that I am using. There are two buttons: 1) raise bid; 2) bid.
Now that being said here is my code

```
<input class="btnraise" type="image" src="bidraise.png" onclick="raiseBid();"/>
<input class="btnbid" type="image" src="mobilebid.png" onclick="Bid();"/
```

That works fine. Except the CEO wanted the buttons to kind of wrap around each other. The raise button is a triangle with a concave bottom where a round circle bid button fits up almost touching the concave bottom of the triangle. (not sure if this makes sense) Almost like a golf ball sitting on a tee upside down. This is the CSS I am using to make them almost touch:

```
.btnbid{
width:250px;
position:relative;
top:-79px;
}

.btnraise{
width:230px;
}
```

Anyway, I need to make these buttons change (like they are indented) when they are pressed. So I did this:

```
<input class="btnraise" type="image" src="bidraise-up.png" onmousedown="this.src='bidraise-down.png'" onmouseup="this.src='bidraise-up.png'" onclick="raiseBid();"/>
<input class="btnbid" type="image" src="mobilebid-up.png" onmousedown="this.src='mobilebid-down.png'" onmouseup="this.src='mobilebid-up.png'" onclick="Bid();"/>
```

That worked just fine on a PC..... But It doesn't work well on a mobile device. The device I have access to is a 3rd or 4th gen iPod Touch. It doesn't change because there is no mouse... I didn't think that one through did I?

So I googled around and found some things that might work. Things like changing the input type from `image` to `button` but then they don't line up right. I lose the round bid image sitting inside the concave part of the triangle. So I was thinking that if I just added both events inside of the `onclick` event then it would work, so I tried this:

```
<input class="btnbid" type="image" src="mobilebid-up.png" onclick="this.src='mobilebid-down.png'; Bid();this.src='mobilebid-up.png';"/>
```

This didn't change the image for the mobile. Any ideas? Do I need to take a different approach to this or is there something different for effects on a mobile site?

**Answer:**

This is what I did: 
1) Added id="btnbid"
2) Added ontouchstart event
3) Added ontouchend event

```
<input id="btnbid" class="btnbid" type="image" src="mobilebid-up.png" ontouchstart="touchStart()" ontouchend="touchEnd()"/>
```

Then I put this in the script tag:

```
var btnbid = document.getElementById('btnbid');
btnbid.addEventListener('touchstart', toucchStart, false);
btnbid.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd, false);

function touchStart( event ) {  
document.getElementById("btnbid").src="mobilebid-down.png";  
 return false;  
} 
function touchEnd( event ) {  
document.getElementById("btnbid").src="mobilebid-up.png";  
return false;  
}
```

This gave me the desired effect!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `onTouch()` instead of `onclick`

Comment: This is an answer. He is using onclick which works with PCs but not with mobiles. He wants it to work with mobiles. My answer of ontouch() is correct and would resolve this issue. This isn't a comment or an opinion.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am on the right track. The image changes now. Is there a way I can capture or display the image while it's being touched and then change when it's not?

Comment: Glad i could be of some help